# R data table: use function on group except current row

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have:

```
x = data.table( id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), price=c(100,110,120,200,200,220) )
> x
   id price
1:  1   100
2:  1   110
3:  1   120
4:  2   200
5:  2   200
6:  2   220
```

and want to find for each row the cheapest price in the group (by=id) once the current row is omitted.
so the results should look like:

```
> x
   id price   cheapest_in_this_id_omitting_current_row
1:  1   100   110       # if I take this row out the cheapest is the next row
2:  1   110   100       # row 1
3:  1   120   100       # row 1
4:  2   200   200       # row 5
5:  2   200   200       # row 4 (or 5)
6:  2   220   200       # row 4 (or 5)
```

So it is like using:

```
x[, cheapest_by_id := min(price), id]
```

but *removing the current row for each calculation*.

If I could have a variable that refers to the current row inside the group like a .row_nb, I would use:

```
x[, min(price[-.row_nb]), id]
```

but this .row_nb does not seem to exist...?

Comment: @akrun I am trying it at the moment. Just have lots of data so it takes a while. Works on the small example for sure. I just have a hard time to figure out how it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We group by 'id', use `combn` on the sequence of row, specify the number of elements to choose i.e. 'm' as 1 less than the number of rows (`.N-1`), use the output from `combn` as numeric index to subset the 'price', get the `min` and assign (`:=`) the output as the new column.

```
 x[,  cheapest_in_this_id_omitting_current_row:= 
             combn(.N:1, .N-1, FUN=function(i) min(price[i])), by = id]
x
#   id price cheapest_in_this_id_omitting_current_row
#1:  1   100                                      110
#2:  1   110                                      100
#3:  1   120                                      100
#4:  2   200                                      200
#5:  2   200                                      200
#6:  2   220                                      200
```

Or instead of using `combn`, we can loop over the sequence, use that to index the 'price', get the `mean`.  I guess this would be fast.

```
 x[,cheapest_in_this_id_omitting_current_row:=
          unlist(lapply(1:.N, function(i) min(price[-i]))) , id]
```

Comment: I tried `sapply` in place of `unlist`-`lapply` and it seemed to also work.

Comment: @Frank If the number of elements are the same, `sapply` converts to matrix.  But, I would prefer `lapply` with `unlist` to avoid any surprises.

Comment: This is a rather profound and surprising answer that has deepened my understanding of combinations.  +1

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
x[order(price), min_other_p := c(price[2], rep(price[1], .N-1)), by = id]
# or
x[order(price), min_other_p := replace( rep(price[1], .N), 1, price[2] ), by = id]


   id price min_other_p
1:  1   100         110
2:  1   110         100
3:  1   120         100
4:  2   200         200
5:  2   200         200
6:  2   220         200
```

The `order` in `i` is not necessary in the OP's example but needed in general.

---

*How it works.* We sort the price vector in increasing order with `order`, so that `price[1]` and `price[2]` are the lowest two prices observed in each group. In the result, we want `price[1]`  -- the lowest price overall -- everywhere except in position 1, where we want the next lowest price.

To be even more explicit: Suppose we have sorted so that we have sorted so that `i==1` is the row with the lowest price within a group; `i==2`, the second lowest and so on. Then `price[1]` is the 1st [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of the vector of prices in a group and `price[2]` is the second order statistic of the vector of prices. It is clear that

```
# pseudocode
min(price[-i]) == price[2] if i==1, since price[2] == min(price[2:.N])
min(price[-i]) == price[1] otherwise, since price[1] belongs to price[-i] and is smallest
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I've added an explanation. I hope its clear. It's kind of strange for me to think about "removing the current row" like this and I had to recheck the OP to see what was meant. I'm always thinking about order statistics in my work.

Comment: I felt it a bit tricky about using the two values per group.  It should be fast.